# work with grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridInboxMessage" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="title" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Body" HeaderText="body" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Body" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Sender" HeaderText="sender" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Sender" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date1" HeaderText="date" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Date1" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ContextTypeName="DataClassesDataContext"
            Select="new (Title, Body, Sender, Date1)" 
            TableName="PrivateMessages" 
            Where="Receptor == @Receptor">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Receptor" QueryStringField="idCompany" Type="String" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

I have an asp:GridView populated from an LinqDataSource. My questions are

1. Body included is 1000 characters I can display only 50 characters in the field of body(over flow hide).
2. field `date` content `1/1/2011` i want show `jul 1 2011` in field `date`
3. field `sender` equal id (example 23) i want show name(23=alen)

How will I achieve all these?

**Edit**

answer @naveen is correct.

i want when user click on row show body full????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

Markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridInboxMessage" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="title" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Title" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Body" SortExpression="Body">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="MyBody" runat="server"
                        Text='<%# TruncateText(Eval("Body"))%>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sender">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="MySender" runat="server"
                        Text='<%# GetSenderNameFromID(Eval("Sender"))%>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="MyDate" runat="server"
                        Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Date1", "{0:MMMM d yyy}")%>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind

```
protected string TruncateText(object objBody)
{
    string truncated = "";
    if (objBody != null)
    {
        truncated = objBody.ToString().Length > 50 ? 
            objBody.ToString().Substring(0, 47) + "..." : objBody.ToString();
    }
    return truncated;
}

protected string GetSenderNameFromID(object objSenderID)
{
    string senderName = "";
    if (objSenderID != null)
    {
        senderName = CallDatabaseToGetNameFromID();
    }
    return senderName;
}

private string CallDatabaseToGetNameFromID()
{
    //implement your database call to retrieve sender name from id
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think for the third one he wants to display the name of the sender, not their ID.  For that he needs to modify his select query as Martin said.

Comment: @Tim: Thanks for that. I guess all is well now.

Comment: @GodIsLive: what happened? why the unmark? any probs with the code?

Comment: i am sorry you have to ask this on another post. its too much of work :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to show the Name of sender and not ID, you have to modify your query to join in the table that contains the name

For date issue, you can use Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")

Can you ensure that your query actually returns all the characters before binding to the grid?

Comment: hey, I'm not doing your work. I have told you what to do. It works.